# addition of a data point from a different column to the preceding data point

Tags: r

I'm having real difficulty performing a calculation that is incredibly easy to perform in excel. What i require is a kind of rolling addition whereby the value in one column is added to preceding data point. For example:

```
column a: 1,2,3,5,16,18,3,11
```

would produce:

```
column b: 1,3,6,11,27,45,48,59
```

i.e. (1+1=2),(2+1=3),(3+3=6),(5+6=11)...

I have a feeling I'm missing something really obvious but have tried various iterations of rollapply and shift with no success... How can I do this in R? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `cumsum`:

```
df = data.frame(a=1:10)
df$b = cumsum(df$a)
```

Comment: So simple!! Thanks very much, that was what i was looking for...